# Running python script with modules via Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to run a python script via ansible. It used to work fine until I start using some additional modules:

My project structure is:

```
roles
--- newclient
--------- files
---------------pythonscript.py
---------------helpers
--------------------- helper.py
```

And I'm running the script via:

```
- name: launch processors and history
  script: script.py 
  delegate_to: localhost
```

The problem is that I run into a `ModuleNotFoundError` when I import the helper via python. I've no idea how to solve this since the script is launched from `.ansible/tmp/`

Answer (score 0):

`script` module copies the script first, then executes it.

In your case only `pythonscript.py` is copied.

Consider rewriting the script without external modules, or manually copy all required files with `copy` or `synchronize` module and execute the script with `command` module.